# Index multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Given I have four lists (in reality I have many more, read in from a CSV as numpy arrays) such that:

```
a = [54,35,67...]
b = [45,21,87...]
c = [32,58,52...]
d = [4,78,43...]
# In reality I have plant % cover surveyed at a location
```

and four lists like:

```
A = ['foo', 'bar', 'ham'...]
B = ['eggs', 'spam', 'bar'...]
C = ['ham', 'eggs', 'foo'...]
D = ['eggs', 'spam', 'bar'...]
# These are plant species
```

I can find the max of a, b, c and d using:

```
max = [a, b, c, d].max(axis=0)
# The max plant % cover between a, b, c and d on the 0 axis
```

to get:

```
max = [54, 78, 87...]
# the plant species that accompanies the max plant % cover
```

but how do I now get the corresponding text value, so my output looks like:

```
Text = ['foo', 'spam', 'bar'...]
```

Comment: Just to clarify. You want the letter/string that is at the same X/Y location as the numbers in Max?

Comment: Yes, I want the letter that corresponds with the max value only

Comment: No, you don't have four arrays, you have four *lists*. At least, that's what you have in your code. And your code would throw an `AttributeError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `argmax` to get the index of the maximum values and [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to pick up the names from the names array:

```
import numpy as np

names = np.array([A, B, C, D])
values = np.array([a, b, c, d])

# use argmax to find out the index of the max values
index_max = values.argmax(0)
​
# use index to pick up corresponding names using advance indexing
names[index_max, np.arange(names.shape[1])]

# array(['foo', 'spam', 'bar'], 
#       dtype='<U4')
```

Comment: What if A, B, C and D are not so straightforward and contain lots of different words that I won't be able to enter manually as "ABCD"? In my actual data its plant species names

Comment: Your example is a little vague to me. Do you mean you really have four lists where each list contains only one unique value?

Comment: Apologies, my error. Yes, I'll edit my question to reflect this